# Are there any cherry trees that produce enjoyable fruit and pink blossoms?

Tags: cherries

I've successfully grown sweet and tart cherries before, but all the varieties I've found have white flowers. I like practical plants, not strictly ornamental, so I'm looking for a variety that offers both pink flowers and enjoyable fruit. Are there any that meet both criteria?

Comment: What climate zone are you in or where are you located?

Comment: I am located in USDA 6a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know. But according to [this](https://www.orangepippintrees.co.uk/questions/what-colour-is-cherry-blossom-10011) UK nursery:

> In fact all sweet cherries have the same plain white blossom. Although
> it is very attractive in spring, sweet cherry blossom cannot really
> compete with the spectactular blossom you see in ornamental cherry
> species.

Answer (score 1):

They're not exactly cherries (but people pass them off as cherries in interspecies hybrids with other fruiting trees in the Prunus genus, at times), but cherry plums (Prunus cerasifera) are supposed to be able to have white or pale pink flowers. You might look for a small-fruited cross between a peach or nectarine and a cherry plum.